# How to calculate accuracy of LSTM neural network for stock prediction?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, lstm

I have made a LST neural network to predict the stock prices (based on close price of previous 60 days) and I am wondering if there is any way to calculate the accuracy of the neural network since the data is continuous. I have calculated the Root mean square error but is there any way to get the accuracy?

Comment: What do you want the accuracy to represent? Accuracy is normally a true/false value so do you want to determine if it perfectly estimated the future value? That does not seem like a very good metric for continuous values, since being off by a small margin is not bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [MAPE](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/MAPE) or Mean Absolute Percentage Error. You can add "mean_absolute_percentage_error" to the metrics when compiling.